# Will a child application inherit from its parent web.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I setup a IIS application from within an existing application.

Will the parents web.config be inherited or is that something I have to set explicitly?

Answer (score 6):

Yes it will without setting anything explicitly, and I don't know any way to prevent it.

However many configuration sections will allow you to clear data inherited from parent files.

E.g.

```
<appSettings>
   <clear/>
   <add key=...>
</appSettings>

<connectionStrings>
   <clear/>
   <add ... />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You can only do it by creating the application in another directory, or change the settings back.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `remove` tag to get rid of things you don't want or put everything in a location and tell it not to inherit:

```
<remove name="FooBar" />

<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
        ...
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: but what about the sections outside of system.web? like <system.webServer>

Comment: not 100% sure, but I believe you can wrap anything in a "location". I haven't tried, would definitely need to test it.

Comment: Elements that are only allowed in "root" web.configs can't be wrapped in a "location".

Answer (score 1):

The child inherits the parent's web.config file.

Also, when a new `web.config` file is created in the child, the child's `web.config` file settings override the same settings in the parent's `web.config` file.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is change the parent .NET 4 app's web.config to indicate its settings shouldn't flow down to the children

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
   <system.web>
    ...your system.web stuff goes here
   </system.web>
</location>
```

For more details refer here
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangingASPNETWebconfigInheritanceWhenMixingVersionsOfChildApplications.aspx