# Why an ASP.NET MVC Configuration Error With Sub Folder as Web Application that cannot load Site Master Type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, server-error

Inside of my MVC application, I have a sub-folder named "Admin" that was "Converted to Web Application".  In IIS, the Admin folder has also been setup as a web-application.

After publishing my full application, I get a Configuration Error when trying to open Default.aspx within the Admin folder.

## EDIT

I made the suggested change and added:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.web>...</system.web>
</location>
```

I am now getting a new error:

> **Parser Error:**
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this  request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message:** Could not load type 'UI.Administration.Site'.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="UI.Administration.Site" %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue with [web.config inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx) (parent project has a reference the child project doesn't). You can find a [related question on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049573/how-do-i-stop-web-config-inheritance) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782252/avoid-web-config-inheritance-in-child-web-application-using-inheritinchildapplica).