# Reporting Services & Web Application (with HTTPHandler)

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We are trying to add SQL Reporting Services to a .Net 2.0 Web Application.  SRS has been installed on the server successfully, but we get an error when we try to load a report or access the report manager:

```
Server Error in '/Reports' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'netGmrc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The error is being coming from a line in the web.config where an httpHandler called Upload.axc is being added to the web application.  The entire httpHandler section is listed below.

```
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="Upload.axd" type="netGmrc.Upload, netGmrc"/>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

When we remove the Upload.axd handler from Web.Config, everything in SRS works fine.  What is the proper way to have Reporting Services work along side the web application with this httphandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that seems to work, which is to change the application's web.config such that the settings are not inherited by Reporting Services.  Preventing the inheritance seems to allow both the Web Application and Reporting Services to function properly.

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.web>
    ...
  </system.web>
</location>
```

This came from [Stack Overflow question #1049573](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049573/how-do-i-stop-web-config-inheritance).