# Can a subdomain web.config file clear inherited settings?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have to deploy an MVC app into a subdomain hosted on GoDaddy.  The root domain is a DotNetNuke site.  When I try to access my app in the subdomain, I get this error:

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DotNetNuke' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I think this is happening because my app is inheriting the settings from the root DNN app, but my bin directory doesn't have the DNN binaries, and so ASP.NET can't find what it needs.

So the question is: how can I specify in my web.config that I want it **not** to inherit the DNN settings from the root directory?

(By the way, I called GoDaddy about this, and their suggestion is "don't put a DNN site on the root, for this exact reason".  They proposed some workarounds, but none as convenient as what I *want* to do, and one day this will happen when I don't control the root site at all, so I'd really like to know how to do this.)

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049573/how-do-i-stop-web-config-inheritance

Comment: The question does appear to be a duplicate, but the answer in that question doesn't help me, because it requires access to the machine configuration, which I don't have with shared hosting.

Comment: OK, sorry. I would remote close vote but there is no way to do that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go Daddy does not support installations of DotNetNuke in the root of your hosting account.  You can review this help guide for more information on this: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1463/can-i-install-dotnetnuke-in-my-root-folder

Comment: I will remove the DNN site from the root, and give the redirect a try.