# .net 4.0 inheriting .net 3.5 web.config?

Tags: asp.net

I have a .NET 3.5 web site in IIS 6. I created a virtual directory to host a .NET 4.0 app. However, I'm getting all kinds of errors that point to the .NET 4.0 app processing items from the parent app's web.config file, even though I have it set up to be its own virtual directory.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: without the actual error, you probebly have HttpModules being added, try using the 

<remove Name="" />


Until it start working.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you - although it explains what to do in the opposite situation.

[Can I host a .net 2.0 virtual directory in asp.net 4.0 site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469732/can-i-host-a-net-2-0-virtual-directory-in-asp-net-4-0-site/3469892#3469892)

Virtual directories will inherit the root directory web.config. This is by design.

Or, you can use the `<remove />` element to, well, remove elements from the parent config.

Answer (score 0):

give different applicaiton pools for the parent and child app from iis. Set framework 2.0 for the parent app's applicaiton pool and framework 4.0 for the child's.