# mstest - unable to get type error

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

I'm getting the following error when using "run all tests in solution" or "run checked tests", but if I use "debug checked tests" they run fine.

Unable to get type TestDataLayer.TestPatientDAO, TestDataLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Error: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'DomainLayer.BaseEntity' from assembly 'DomainLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

DomainLayer.BaseEntity is an abstract class.

Removing and adding the reference to DomainLayer again didn't help.

Unloading and loading TestDataLayer or DomainLayer didn't help.

edit:
removing and adding CodeCoverage solved the problem (wtf)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding as an answer to help others discover a possible solution to this problem:

As per myAces, I was getting a TypeLoadException when running MSTest unit tests from within Visual studio 2010. Debugging the tests would work flawlessly, Running the tests via the Resharper tests would pass flawlessly.

Like myAces, the **Code Coverage** was the problem. To fix I performed the following:

Test Menu -> Edit Test Settings -> Local

Data and Dianostics -> Untick the Code coverage option -> Apply & Close

Then reapplied Code Coverage to required assemblies and everything works fine.

Comment: Surprisingly appeared to be much more useful than http://stackoverflow.com/a/8824250/934618 :)

Comment: Thank you Ash! Though I am using VS 2012, un-checking the Test (menu)-> Test Settings - > ($SolutionPath)\licaltestrun.testrunconfig solved the problem.