# Gets Unable to load one or more of the requested types after moving the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I recently moved my asp.net project from my old development pc (Win7, VS2005, SQL Server 2005, .net 2.0, .net 3.5) to a new PC (Win8, VS2012, SQL Server 2008 R2, .net 2.0, .net 3.5, .net 4.5).

I can debug it as normal and it runs on development server. But when I try to publish the project I get the following error

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information.

I tried following solution and they did not solve my problem.

- Setting reference copy local to TRUE
- adding trust level full in `web.config`
- Checking fusion logs (it's empty)

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? If so, make sure you've set the reference copy local to these as well: 
System.Data.Entity; 
System.Web.Entity;

Also, try the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091853/error-message-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-retrieve-the-l

Comment: Remove Temp Files that may problem or check added references are updated

Answer (score 0):

I just turned off **"generate Serialization assembly"** for **Release Configuration** in properties and it worked without any other fixes.