# ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information in WP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xamarin, mvvmcross

Getting this error while running WP project but Android working fine. I Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091853/error-message-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-retrieve-the-l/%22this%22) link and tried all options but no luck. It does not fire an error in code side, only display error message on output window, so unable to debug it and app does not get started. Please help to resolve this.

Getting this error :

> ******************* MVXApp.Initialize 
>   mvx:Diagnostic: 26.16 Setup: ViewModelTypeFinder start
>   mvx:Diagnostic: 26.17 Setup: ViewsContainer start
>   mvx:Diagnostic: 26.18 Setup: ViewDispatcher start
>   mvx:Diagnostic: 26.18 Setup: Views start
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   mvx:Warning: 26.36 ReflectionTypeLoadException masked during loading of MspManager.App.Phone81, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null - error ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
>      at Cirrious.CrossCore.ReflectionExtensions.GetTypes(Assembly assembly)
>      at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxTypeExtensions.ExceptionSafeGetTypes(Assembly assembly)
>
> mvx:Diagnostic: 26.36 Setup: CommandCollectionBuilder start
>   mvx:Diagnostic: 26.37 Setup: NavigationSerializer start
>   mvx:Diagnostic: 26.37 Setup: InpcInterception start
>   mvx:Diagnostic: 26.38 Setup: LastChance start
>   mvx:Diagnostic: 26.38 Setup: Secondary end
>   mvx:Diagnostic: 26.43 Showing ViewModel LoginViewModel
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in Cirrious.MvvmCross.DLL
>   mvx:Diagnostic: 26.57 Error seen during navigation request to LoginViewModel - error KeyNotFoundException: Could not find view for MspManager.App.Core.ViewModels.LoginViewModel
>          at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxViewsContainer.GetViewType(Type viewModelType)
>      at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.MvxPhoneViewsContainer.GetXamlUriFor(MvxViewModelRequest request)
>      at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.MvxPhoneViewPresenter.Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)

Comment: Do you have your project setup as a shared project or PCL? Also can you share your code for your LoginViewModel?

Comment: @CookData: I have PCL project and [here](https://github.com/Uddhao/WP/blob/master/LoginViewModel) is my LoginViewModel code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. The problem was i using  Chance.MvvmCross.plugins.UserInteraction plugin in my project, it is for MvvmCross v3. Now replace Birdie.MvvmCross.plugins.UserInteraction instead of Chance.MvvmCross.plugins.UserInteraction for MvvmCross v4 and issue get resolved.