# How to diagnose Resharper Unit Test Runner "Unable to load one or more of the requested types" error

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, resharper

When I run or debug my unit tests using Resharper Unit Test Runner, I get a dialog popping up that says "Unit Test Runner failed to run tests - Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information":

[image]

Now I have tried rebuilds, cleans, manually deleting folders, visual studio restarts, hardware restarts, looking in output/debug windows, and evening enabling R# "internal" mode so that I can see it's logs (written to %Temp%\JetLogs as I understand), but none of that resolves it or gives any clues at all. I have tried "debugging" R# but again the dialog pops up before the debugger hits any exceptions.

How the hell am I supposed to resolve this? It's extremely annoying!

I'm using:

- R# 2016.1.2
- NUnit 3.2.1
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 (14.0.25123)

Comment: It does seem this error is coming directly from Nunit, but I am surprised that R# does not do anything to help me diagnose this...

Comment: Resharper doesn't get a chance to, as NUnit catches the exceptions and morphs in a Failed Test Result (without all the details, that is the real problem).

Answer (score 17):

I ended up diagnosing this with a fairly simple method:

I converted my unit test assembly from a class library into a console application and added a Main entry point (shown below). Within there I iterate all of the assemblies types which I hoped would cause all types & dependent assemblies to be loaded, which would reveal any load exceptions. And yes it worked. It quickly threw a `System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException` which is the canonical source of the error message "Unable to load one or more...". In the debugger I could examine the `LoaderExceptions` property which told me what the underlying problem was.

```
public class Program
{ 
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
    }
}
```

Comment: And by doing this (sorry, couldn't get my code to look good in the comment), I got a popup telling me exactly what assembly it couldn't load, and why. In my case, the real problem was a mix of strongly signed and unsigned assemblies:
            `try
            {
                var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
            {
                foreach (var item in ex.LoaderExceptions)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(item.Message);
                }
            }`

Comment: You would think that Resharper Test Runner would have a way to catch that Exception and allow you to retrieve it without having to write it yourself.

Answer (score 12):

Schneider's answer will work just fine but if there are more lazy people out there you can check the `LoaderExceptions` in PowerShell a bit faster.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('<path to your assembly>') | % {$_.GetTypes()}
$Error[0].Exception.InnerException.LoaderExceptions
```

Comment: `<path to your assembly>` must be an absolute path

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem in Visual Studio 2017 by closing Visual Studio, deleting the `.vs` and `obj` folders of the assembly which wouldn't load, and then reopening Visual Studio and running the tests again.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with visual studio Express 2017. Tried Schneider's approach but no exception was thrown. Eventually, I created a new project and moved all files of the project that had this problem to the new project and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and finally got it working by installing this nuget package (was unit testing a mvc core project)
Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk