# C# Windows Service wont install if it includes (embedded) Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-services, installutil

I've been trying to work out why my C# Windows service won't install and it seems to be being caused by including Entity Framework.

To test this, I created a new project using the Windows Service template in Visual Studio and just let the wizard do its thing.

Deployed to my test server, installed and everything worked as expected... I then uninstalled.

Next, I added (DB First) Entity Framework model to the project, again something very basic and deployed to server..

This time, when I install, I get the following..

> Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version
>   4.0.30319.17929 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of
>   the log file for the D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.exe assembly's
>   progress. The file is located at
>   D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.InstallLog. Installing assembly
>   'D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.exe'. Affected parameters are:
>   logtoconsole =     logfile =
>   D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.InstallLog    assemblypath =
>   D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.exe An exception occurred while
>   trying to find the installers in the
>   D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.exe assembly.
>   System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or
>   more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property
>   for more information. Aborting installation for
>   D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.exe.
>
> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to get installer types in the
>   D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.exe assembly. The inner exception
>   System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException was thrown with the
>   following error message: Unable to load one or more of the requested
>   types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information..
>
> The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning. See the contents
>   of the log file for the D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.InstallLog. Rolling back assembly
>   'D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.exe'. Affected parameters are:
>   logtoconsole =     logfile =
>   D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.InstallLog    assemblypath =
>   D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.exe An exception occurred while
>   trying to find the installers in the
>   D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.exe assembly.
>   System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or
>   more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property
>   for more information. Aborting installation for
>   D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.exe. An exception occurred during
>   the Rollback phase of the
>   System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller installer.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to get installer types in the
>   D:\SandBox\TestService\TestService.exe assembly. The inner exception
>   System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException was thrown with the
>   following error message: Unable to load one or more of the requested
>   types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information..
>   An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation.
>   This exception will be ignored and the rollback will continue.
>   However, the machine might not fully revert to its initial state after
>   the rollback is complete.
>
> The Rollback phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed. The installation failed, and the
>   rollback has been performed.

When the service was deployed, I copied the *EntityFramework.dll* and *EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll* with the *exe* and *config* files and are all in the same folder.

So, what explicitly is *InstallUtil* complaining about. How can I find out

FYI: "Works on my machine" as per any developer problem

**EDIT:**

References to this SO question [Error message 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091853/error-message-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-retrieve-the-l) are when something goes wrong during **RUNTIME** ... My specific issue is during **INSTALL**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091853/error-message-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-retrieve-the-l)

Comment: The above comment is true in some respects but that's when a error occurs at runtime... My question specifically relates a failure to install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have managed to resolve/work around the problem.

Rather than have the EF model within the service application, I hived it off into its own class library and then just added that as a reference and voilà, install successful.

Comment: How are you and I the only two people to have ever had this problem? Thanks for taking the time to post an answer to your own question, it really helped me out.

Comment: @msulis - Glad it helped someone.