# Grpc: C# server as a Windows Service is it possible?

Tags: c#, windows-services, grpc

Im trying to pass the source code of a C# Grpc server into a Windows Service Project.
Following [these steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) but when I execute InstallUtil MyService.exe the process stops indicating

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: No se pueden cargar uno o varios
tipos requeridos. Recupere la propiedad LoaderExceptions para obtener más información.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Copy Local attribute of project's references to true.

More info here: [Error message 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091853/error-message-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-retrieve-the-l)

Answer (score 0):

InstallUtil is for installation of windows service, which we are using earlier for .net framework. As this will be in .net Core, we need to use a cs command.

Following is the example command you can use:

```
sc.exe create NewServiceName binpath=pathOfExe
```

You need to use a CS command as specified in following link because this is a .net Core application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).