# Reflections is not working when using Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, reflection

I've created a console app which gets dlls from folder and uses reflection in order to extract the methods out of each dll, it works fine on my local machine, but when I use this app from Jenkins server, I get error for each

> file (could not be loaded: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.)

is that a known issue? what could be the problem?

Comment: are your dlls set as copied to local?

Comment: Jenkins aside, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091853/error-message-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-retrieve-the-l?rq=1)

Comment: All my references are set to 'copy local - true', is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: What do you mean by `but when I use this app from Jenkins`? You have a Jenkins job that builds your app, and when you test the binaries, they don't work as expected? If that's the case, I suggest taking a step back from Jenkins and try to build/debug your app from the terminal until you get the expected result. I assume you use `VS`, in that case, you should play with the `msbuild`. I believe this is a configuration issue.

Comment: thanks all, I was missing some dll's in the Jenkins machine