# System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, .net-assembly, .net-5

I am building an API on Visual Studio 2019 net5.0 and I was just adding the lasts controllers and validators when my program suddenly stopped working.

The error that I'm getting:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'Crijoya.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.
Could not load file or assembly 'Crijoya.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.
Could not load file or assembly 'Crijoya.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.
Could not load file or assembly 'Crijoya.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.
Could not load file or assembly 'Crijoya.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.
Could not load file or assembly 'Crijoya.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.
Could not load file or assembly 'Crijoya.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.
Could not load file or assembly 'Crijoya.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.
Could not load file or assembly 'Crijoya.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.'
```

I get this error on my Statup ConfigureServices method when loading the assemblies. Here's the code:

```
//use and register all the mappings
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

I have tried following these solutions but I can't get to the problem:
[Error message 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091853/error-message-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-retrieve-the-l)

Comment: Can you see the inner exception or more information about the exception?
Another silly idea is that the file `Crijoya.Core.dll` has become corrupt, this can be because the file is not complete, or because of a wrong setting in an FTP program the dll was treated as text and newlines are converted (windows/linux style)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly ... An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format (System.BadImageFormatException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a)

Comment: @ChristopheDevos I have tried all but nothing seems to work. It suddenly stopped working so I don't think it's a platform issue. But I have tried to enable the 32bit, check the 64 bit, etc. Nothing works. I have copied my bin file that I had from previous copies of the project so the problem seems to be on the dll files. Don't know how to solve it though

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091853/error-message-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-retrieve-the-l) can help you

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT I already tried everything they said there but I managed to make it work for me in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in my case the dll file Crijoya.Core was in a different format as the error says. After trying everything they said on other questions this is what worked for me.

I have a project with two class libraries like so

[image]

I made sure that in the properties of each of them the platform was Any CPU

[image]

And finally that on Tools I was using the 64 bit version for IIS Express for web projects

[image]

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)