# Unable to load one or more of the requested types - ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nuget, asp.net-core-6.0

ASP.NET Core 6.0 web app. I get an error when I try to map controllers in `Startup.cs`. The assembly referenced (`QESI.Accuracy.Contract`) is a project reference, and it works fine.

The line above it loads a class from that project with no issues. This particular assembly is also packaged and used in other solutions, so I'm wondering if something is trying to load the Nuget package instead of the project reference and that is what's causing it to fail.

[image: Exception]

If I change the name of the assembly for the project to suffix a `2` I get an error that the same type exists in two assemblies. So something somewhere is referencing the version 1.1.58, which would be the nuget package. I've cleared all nuget package caches using [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders).

[image: Changed Name]

Comment: Can this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091853/error-message-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-retrieve-the-l) help you?

Comment: didn't help.. I've tried everything suggested :(

Comment: This error message  has no true answer, It related to your project, I think you can only to find the reason by yourself.

Comment: the only way I was able to fix it was by moving the contract package to a completely separate solution, building the nuget package, and consuming that package in the app. :(