# throw error when Add migration In .net 8 upgraded project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, migration, .net-8.0

I upgraded my project to `.Net 8` Now to add migrations with the   `add-migration` command, I encounter the following error :

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
> Method 'AddReplacements' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CaseCorrection.VisualBasicCaseCorrectionService'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
> does not have an implementation.
> Method 'AddLexicalClassifications' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Classification.VisualBasicSyntaxClassificationService'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
> does not have an implementation.
> Method 'AddLexicalClassifications' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Classification.VisualBasicEditorClassificationService'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
> does not have an implementation.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeGeneration.AbstractCodeGenerationService'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> Method 'CreateExplicitlyCastedLiteralValue' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CodeGeneration.VisualBasicFlagsEnumGenerator'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
> does not have an implementation.
> Method 'get_ElasticMarker' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CodeGeneration.VisualBasicSyntaxGenerator'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
> does not have an implementation.
> Derived method 'EndOfLine' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CodeGeneration.VisualBasicSyntaxGeneratorInternal'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
> cannot reduce access.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Options.Providers.IOptionProvider' from
> assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EmbeddedLanguages.LanguageServices.AbstractEmbeddedLanguagesProvider'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> Method 'get_SyntaxFacts' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.EmbeddedLanguages.VirtualChars.VisualBasicVirtualCharService'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
> does not have an implementation.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.AbstractDeclaredSymbolInfoFactoryService`9' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Method 'LineContinuationFollowedByWhitespaceComment' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Formatting.VisualBasicTriviaFormatter' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method 'get_HeaderFacts' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Formatting.VisualBasicFormatEngine' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method 'get_HeaderFacts' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Formatting.VisualBasicStructuredTriviaFormatEngine' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Formatting.AbstractSyntaxFormattingService' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Method 'get_SyntaxFacts' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Indentation.VisualBasicIndentationService' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.TextChange>> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Indentation.ISmartTokenFormatter.FormatTokenAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxToken, System.Threading.CancellationToken)'. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.ISemanticFacts' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document>
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.OrganizeImports.IOrganizeImportsService.OrganizeImportsAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Recommendations.AbstractRecommendationService`1' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Recommendations.AbstractRecommendationServiceRunner`1'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> Method 'IsIdentifierValid' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Rename.VisualBasicRenameRewriterLanguageService'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
> does not have an implementation.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SemanticModelReuse.AbstractSemanticModelReuseLanguageService`4' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Method 'IsApplicable' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Simplification.VisualBasicCallReducer' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method 'IsApplicable' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Simplification.VisualBasicCastReducer' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method 'IsApplicable' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Simplification.VisualBasicEscapingReducer' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method 'IsApplicable' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Simplification.VisualBasicExtensionMethodReducer' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method 'IsApplicable' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Simplification.VisualBasicInferredMemberNameReducer' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method 'IsApplicable' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Simplification.VisualBasicMiscellaneousReducer' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method 'IsApplicable' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Simplification.VisualBasicNameReducer' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method 'IsApplicable' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Simplification.VisualBasicParenthesesReducer' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method 'IsApplicable' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Simplification.VisualBasicVariableDeclaratorReducer' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Simplification.Simplifiers.AbstractSimplifier`2'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Simplification.Simplifiers.AbstractSimplifier`2' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Simplification.Simplifiers.AbstractSimplifier`2'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> Method 'NodeRequiresNonSpeculativeSemanticModel' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Simplification.VisualBasicSimplificationService'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
> does not have an implementation.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Shared.Utilities.AbstractSpeculationAnalyzer`7' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Method 'TryParsePdbCompilationOptions' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicCompilationFactoryService' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method 'GetUnnecessaryImports' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.RemoveUnnecessaryImports.VisualBasicUnnecessaryImportsProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Method 'get_UnnecessaryImportsProvider' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.RemoveUnnecessaryImports.VisualBasicRemoveUnnecessaryImportsService' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.AbstractSelectedMembers`5'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.IAccessibilityFacts' from
> assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.AbstractDocumentationCommentService`10' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.AbstractFileBannerFacts' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.AbstractHeaderFacts' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.ISyntaxFacts' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.ISyntaxKinds' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.AbstractFileBannerFacts' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.AbstractHeaderFacts' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.AddImports.AbstractAddImportsService`4' from
> assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.AbstractSemanticFactsService'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.ISymbolDeclarationService'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServices.TypeInferenceService.AbstractTypeInferenceService'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.8.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeCleanup.Providers.ICodeCleanupProvider.CleanupAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.TextSpan>,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.
> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeCleanup.Providers.ICodeCleanupProvider.CleanupAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.TextSpan>,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.
> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeCleanup.Providers.ICodeCleanupProvider.CleanupAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.TextSpan>,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.
> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeCleanup.Providers.ICodeCleanupProvider.CleanupAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.TextSpan>,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.
> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeCleanup.Providers.ICodeCleanupProvider.CleanupAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.TextSpan>,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.
> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeCleanup.Providers.ICodeCleanupProvider.CleanupAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.TextSpan>,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.
> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeCleanup.Providers.ICodeCleanupProvider.CleanupAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.TextSpan>,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.
> Method 'get_SyntaxFacts' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.EmbeddedLanguages.VirtualChars.VisualBasicVirtualCharService'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
> does not have an implementation.
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeCleanup.Providers.ICodeCleanupProvider.CleanupAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document,
> System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.TextSpan>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)'. Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document>
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeCleanup.Providers.ICodeCleanupProvider.CleanupAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document,
> '.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091853/error-message-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-retrieve-the-l)

Comment: Can you please share your csproj file. Ideally a [mre]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same error.  When I upgraded `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` *references to version 8.0.0*, I had to also updated my `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` *references to version 4.8.0* to resolve build errors.  This let me rebuild my solution with no errors.

However, I still had the error about not being able to resolve types in `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces version 4.4.0`.  I was stumped because I did not have any references to version 4.4.0 in my project file.

I realized that I did not have an explicit reference to `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces` in my project file, so VS was automatically referencing the old version of that library.

**Solution**: Add lines to your project file, with specific versions for the `CodeAnalysis libraries`.  Here are my references that work:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" Version="4.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common" Version="4.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic" Version="4.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces" Version="4.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="4.8.0" />
```

Comment: thanks! that helped. I wonder why we need to set all of these references manually?!